# Visual Studio Code Blank HTML Output for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, stringr, vscode-remote

I am taking a data-science class in R. I am using vscode remote-SSH from a computer that is at home. The current unit about `stringr` and REGEX expressions. When I use the `str_view` function to show how the strings match the REGEX expressions, I get a blank output:

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxaqg.png)

I am not sure where to start to fix this. Please tell me what you need. I will update my post with whatever.

Thanks!